# Why does this bitshifting work? (for printing numbers as binarys)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I saw the code and was wondering why this is working:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void printBinary (unsigned int number)
{
 unsigned int mask = 0;

    for(mask = 1 << 31; mask!=0; mask >>=1)

      {
    if (number & mask)
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("0");

      }
printf ("\n");
}

int main()
{
    printBinary (10);
    return 0;

    unsigned int suffix = 24;


    return 0;
}
```

I imagine the void function like this:
at first we have

mask: 100000000000000... (32times zero) and
number: 0000000000000000000001010

the it compares both numbers with & and they are different, so 0 is posted.
next loop:

01000000000....

0000000000000000000001010

same here. When it comes to

00000000000000001000

00000000000000001010

(number & mask) will be true, but still both numbers are differnt. It's like it is only comparing that the binary numbers where the 1 currently is in the upper number. But since mask and number as such is compared it should only print 1 if they are completely the same. So what I don't understand is why a 1 is printed here instead of a 0. I think a 1 should only be printed if it's

0000000000000001010

0000000000000001010

I hope it is clear what my question is, maybe someone can explain to me how this loop works in detail.

Thanks!

Comment: `if (n)` is true for *any non-zero value* of `n`.

Comment: In C, "non-zero" means "true" when performing comparison and bitwise operations, hence why it's branching to output "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a bitwise AND operation, so

```
00000000000000001000 & 00000000000000001010
```

evaluates to

```
00000000000000001000
```

which is different from 0, and in C

```
if (number & mask)
```

is shorthand for

```
if ((number & mask) != 0)
```

Comment: Ah, I just tried it with ( 2 & 10) and it also gives me a true value. Thank you very much, appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The work is done by this algorithm:

```
   for(mask = 1 << 31; mask!=0; mask >>=1) {
     if (number & mask)
        printf("1");
     else
        printf("0");
    }
```

The first thing to understand is the "mask" - the mask here is a 32-bit integer with EXACTLY 1 bit set to 1 and all the others are zero.  You seem to have understood that the mask starts as "1000000...000" and on each successive loop, the "1" in the mask is shifted to the right (mask >>= 1).  So the sequence on successive loop iterations is: "01000....000", "001000...000", ... "0000... 00010", "0000...00001"

The next thing is the "&" operator - "bit-wise AND" - when 2 numbers are "bit-wise AND"ed together, the result will have 1 bits ONLY in positions where both the inputs had 1 bits.  So, for example, "00010" & "11010" == "00010". Since your "mask" only has 1 bit set, the result of (number & mask) will be identical to the mask itself if the bit in that same positiion in number is a 1 and will be 0 if not.

Lastly, we note that in C, 0 is false and ANYTHNG else is considered true.

Thus, we can read the loop above as follows:

```
For each bit from position 31 to position 0:
    if that bit is a 1 in the number:
        print 1
    else:
        print 0
```

Voila - the number is printed in its binary form.

Answer (score 1):

the bitwise AND (`&`) result is a number in which all the bits that were set (1) in the 2 operands, are set.
this means that if a single bit matches, just as you observed, the result will be a non-zero number, which evaluates to TRUE

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis of the code is pretty much correct.
However you have not quite understood how the bitwise & operator works.

The output of & for 2 bits is given by this table

```
       bit 2
        1  0
        ____
bit   0|0  0 
  1   1|1  0
```

For bigger numbers the & compares the bit at the same index in each number in turn and produces an output based on table above so you only get a 1 in the output if there is a 1 in the same location in both inputs. So for your example numbers you get

```
00000000000000001000  //input 1
00000000000000001010  //input 2

00000000000000001000  //output
```

Now any non zero number equates to true so the if statement will enter the print "1" case. I prefer the more explicit code

```
if( (number & mask) != 0 )
```

Basically all the loop is doing is working through the number a bit at a time and testing if it is 1 or zero and printing the corresponding character.

Comment: Yes, I didn't get the & correctly. Emphazises on "did". Thank you very much for your detailed answer, appreciate.